# Migrating to Axon Server

Tags: axon, axon-framework

Currently I am running Axon Framework and using Postgresql as the event store. I am investigating how to scale this horizontally but adding nodes via the k8s HPA functionality regularly results in errors

> org.axonframework.modelling.command.ConcurrencyException: An event for aggregate [x] at sequence [y] was already inserted

I was reading that Axon Server enables this type of scaling but I cannot find anything on migrating the current event store to Axon Server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems my google skills are lacking. Found the process here:
https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-server/migration/non-axon-server-to-axon-server

This only covers migration to Axon Server EE though so I will have to dig more I guess.